# how to reverse mktime() function in PHP?

Tags: php, function, time, reverse, mktime

I am using following to convert time to integer

`mktime(hour,minute,second,month,day,year)`

How would I reverse this to get desired Date? Currently I do not need Minutes or Seconds so I am using Zeroes '0' for them. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [function date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

```
$yourtime = mktime(...);
date("d/m/Y h", $yourtime);
```

Comment: date('Y-m-d H:00:00', $yourtime);

Comment: This isn't a proper reversal, which would return a set of integers from a unix timestamp, not a string.

Answer (score 2):

If your data came from an HTML form, you can use this instead of mktime():

```
$time = strtotime($_GET['time']);
$rounded = $time - $time % 3600; // rounds down to the last hour
```

Then just use:

```
date ('Y-m-d',$rounded);
```

to display the date.

Comment: thx for the suggestion but i need that time in INT value of unix timestamp

Comment: thanks stillstanding, strtotime() actually simplified whole bunch of stuff for me, thanks a lot, this has been great help on another page.

Comment: [gmdate](http://uk1.php.net/gmdate) will always return the time in GMT (there are are a couple of other GMT conversion functions, e.g. [gmmktime](http://uk1.php.net/manual/en/function.gmmktime.php), [gmstrftime](http://uk1.php.net/manual/en/function.gmstrftime.php).  Remember that Unix timestamps are always expressed in UTC/GMT.

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for [`getdate()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getdate.php), it returns associative array with seconds, minutes, hours, etc.

```
// make some time value
$time = time();
// get date components
$d = getdate($time);
// make a new time value with time values reset
$time = mktime(0, 0, 0, $d[‘mon’], $d[‘mday’], $d[‘year’]);
```

Failing that you might want to look at [`idate()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.idate.php) which returns the same values as `date()` but as an integer instead of string which might perform better in case you don’t actually want strings.